# Populate RecyclerView with FirestoreDatabase collection in Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

I have a collection in my Firestore with several documents. I am trying to retrieve those documents and populate a RecyclerView with the data. If I try to populate the RecyclerView with a  simple MutableList it works, but it fails with the Firestore data.

```
var drills: MutableList<Drill> = mutableListOf(
    Drill("Australia","Beroketa ariketa","irudia.com")
)

private fun populateList() {
    FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("drills").document("Hamaika").get()
        .addOnSuccessListener {
                drills.add(Drill(it.get("izena") as String?, it.get("desk") as String?,
                    it.get("irudia") as String?
                ))
            }
        }

fun initRecycler(){
    recyclerViewId.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val adapter = DrillAdapter(drills)
    recyclerViewId.adapter = adapter
}
```

I have also tried to do it with all the documents, but the recyclerView is printing empty:

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("drills").get().addOnSuccessListener { result ->
        for (document in result) {
            val izena = document.get("izena") as String?
           val desk = document.get("desk") as String?
            val irudia = document.get("irudia") as String?
            val ariketa = Drill(izena, desk, irudia)
            drills.add(ariketa)}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: When you debug it are you seeing that data is returned?

Comment: I think that I am not retrieveing properly the data from firestore, as I can populate the recycler with a handmade MutableList, but not with the firestore data. So I am not able to see the List data when debugging.

Comment: It's unclear where the problem comes from, so I recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and adding more debugging information (i.e. step through the code line-by-line in a debugger and check all variables at each step). --- That said, are you calling `recyclerViewId.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you add items to the `drills` list?

Comment: Yes, I call populateList(), notifyDataSetChanged() and initRecycler() inside the onCreate method.

Comment: Through debugger seems like it is not entering in the addOnSuccessListener, so the list is not beeing updated.

Comment: Have you tried to add the onFailureListener to if something is wrong?

Comment: I am getting an error 'mapper 4.x is not supported'. Does it have something in common with my issue?